# Why style command does not work inside noscript section?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="div_popup_content" style="display:none;">
    <h1>Atención Javascript desactivado</h1>
    <p class="red">Javascript deactivado, imposible utilizar la aplicación</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Solución :</p>
    <p style="font-size: 85%;">Internet Explorer : Opciones de internet &gt;
    seguridad internet &gt; Activar Automatización, active scripting</p>
    <p style="font-size: 85%;">Google Chrome : Herramientas &gt; Configuración
    &gt; Privacidad &gt; Configuración de contenido &gt; Permitir
    javascript</p>
</div>
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
      .menu  {display:none; }  
      .div_popup_content {display:block;}; 
    </style>
</noscript>
```

This is a section I have to show if javascript is disabled.
I dont want to see it on design mode (dreamweaver), so I have it hidden and I show it if neccesary using the code inside  .
It seems it only work hidding but not showing.
Also I have played to left property, but it does not work either.

Any help ? Thanks

Comment: Your `<style>` should be under `<head>`

Comment: @NathanLee I know that's illegal construct but still the browser would interpret it as a style. NO?

Comment: Why don't you put the whole div in the noscript part?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui According to this page when `<noscript>` isn't in the `<head>` and scripting is disabled the only thing allowed in that tag is transparent content. So that would mean that `<style>` would not be allowed at that point. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript

Comment: Thanks Matthew, this is...

Answer (score 2):

The better solution to achieve this is normally put a class on the body (i.e. class="no-js") and use javascript to remove it. In this way you can use the selector .some-class to style elements when javascript is enabled and .no-js .some-class to style elements when there is no javascript support.